# Catch multiple string occurrences in multiline text

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

Iv'e been at it for some time now, I'm trying to extract a number of values from
a string pattern in a multiline text using re.findall with no luck.

text:

```
RX[0]
qpn : 0x48
cqn : 0x80
rxBytes : 179531811
rxPackets : 296242
rxPacketsDropped : 0
rxCheckSumOk : 225257
rxCheckSumNone : 200
RX[1]
qpn : 0x49
cqn : 0x81
rxBytes : 0
rxPackets : 0
rxPacketsDropped : 0
rxCheckSumOk : 0
rxCheckSumNone : 0**
```

i need to extract the index -> `RX[index]`
and the `rxPackets : value`

if i split to sections than i can use -

```
re.findall('RX\[(\d+)\].*rxPackets\s*:\s*(\d+)', section, re.DOTALL)
```

but i'm looking to do this with a single regex pattern.
can any one help me shed some light on how to do this?

Comment: I suspect findall will return a list with all the instances. You only have to index the list to find the (eg.) rxPackets you want

Comment: it returns a list containing 1 element the first index and the last rxPackets value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
>>> txt='''\
... RX[0]
... qpn : 0x48
... cqn : 0x80
... rxBytes : 179531811
... rxPackets : 296242
... rxPacketsDropped : 0
... rxCheckSumOk : 225257
... rxCheckSumNone : 200
... RX[1]
... qpn : 0x49
... cqn : 0x81
... rxBytes : 0
... rxPackets : 0
... rxPacketsDropped : 0
... rxCheckSumOk : 0
... rxCheckSumNone : 0**
... '''
>>> import re 
>>> re.search(r'RX\[(\d+)\].*?rxPackets\s+:\s+(\d+)', txt, re.S).groups()
('0', '296242')
```

Or, with findall:

```
>>> re.findall(r'RX\[(\d+)\].*?rxPackets\s+:\s+(\d+)', txt, re.S)
[('0', '296242'), ('1', '0')]
```

Compare with using the greedy form of `.*`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'RX\[(\d+)\].*rxPackets\s+:\s+(\d+)', txt, re.S)
[('0', '0')]
```

Which you can see visually here for [greedy](https://regex101.com/r/pD0bU4/1) and [not greedy](https://regex101.com/r/pD0bU4/2)

Comment: im trying to get a list containing the tuples of all the blocks
[('0',296242'),('1','0')....]

Comment: Doesn't findall in the example I posted do that?

Comment: The key is using the non-greedy `.*?` vs greed `.*`

Answer (score 0):

I am too stupid to use a regex to solve this.

```
rxDict = dict()
key = ''
for line in lines:
    if 'RX' in line:
    key = line.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0]
    if key != '':
       if 'rxPackets' in line:
            rxDict[key] = line.split(':').strip()
            key = ''
```